# Unexpected behavior for address was accidentally rewritten in C++ class when try to write a simple Adjacency list class

Tags: c++, linux

I was try to write a simple Adjacency list class in C++,the structure is something like this:
[Adjacency List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUzdg.png)
.The class has a method addEdge and override ostream method;
here is the code

```
template <typename T>
struct head_node{
    T data;
    struct edge_node *firstNode;
};

struct edge_node{
    int idx;
    double weight;
    struct edge_node *next; 
    bool valid = false; 
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const edge_node &e){
        out<<"idx:"<<e.idx<<" weight:"<<e.weight<<" valid:"<<e.valid<<endl;
        return out;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class Graph{

    private:
        vector<head_node<T>> head_list;
        unordered_map<T,int> data2idx;//Store the location of each data in the head_list

    public:
        Graph(){

        }
        bool addEdge(T from,T to ,double weight ){
            //add new vertex to head_list
            if(data2idx.count(from)==0){
                struct edge_node dummy = {-1,-1,nullptr,false};                
                head_node<T> newNode = {from,&dummy};

                head_list.push_back(newNode);
                data2idx[from] = head_list.size()-1;
            }
            if(data2idx.count(to)==0){
                struct edge_node dummy = {-1,-1,nullptr,false};
                head_node<T> newNode = {to,&dummy};

                head_list.push_back(newNode);
                data2idx[to] = head_list.size()-1;
            }
            //Insert edge vertices into corresponding head vertices
            edge_node* tmp_node = head_list[data2idx[from]].firstNode;
            struct edge_node newEdgeNode ={data2idx[to],weight,tmp_node,true};
            head_list[data2idx[from]].firstNode = &newEdgeNode; 
            //FOR DEBUG
            cout<<*this<<endl;
            return true;
        }

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out ,const Graph &G){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < G.head_list.size();i++){
                head_node<T> head = G.head_list[i];
                out<<head.data<<" : ";
                struct edge_node* e = head.firstNode;
                out<<"address:"<<e<<endl;
                out<<*e;
                //out<<*e;
                /*while(e->valid){
                    out<<"->idx:"<<e->idx<<" weight:"<<e->weight<<" ";
                    //out<<endl<<typeid(e).name();
                    //out<<endl<<typeid(e->next).name();
                    out<<endl<<"valid:"<<e->valid<<endl;
                    e = e->next;
                }*/
            }
            return out;
        }

};
```

And here is the test code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "graph.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    Graph<char> graph;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    while(n--){
        char from,to;
        double weight;
        cin>>from>>to>>weight;
        graph.addEdge(from,to,weight);
    }
    cout<<graph;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compile it with:

> g++ code.cpp graph.cpp -o code

and run it , I insert 2 edge into it ,and want to print every head node and its first node,however it output

```
2
1 3 4
1 : address:0x7ffe10454130
idx:1 weight:4 valid:1
3 : address:0x7ffe10454130
idx:1 weight:4 valid:1

2 3 5
1 : address:0x7ffe10454130
idx:1 weight:5 valid:1
3 : address:0x7ffe10454130
idx:1 weight:5 valid:1
2 : address:0x7ffe10454130
idx:1 weight:5 valid:1
```

and it shows every head node is at the same address , and I can't figure it out , can anyone help?
and here is my g++ details:

> Using built-in specs. COLLECT_GCC=g++
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
>   OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1 Target:
>   x86_64-linux-gnu Configured with: ../src/configure -v
>   --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu Thread model: posix gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

Comment: You can't store a pointer you acquired with `&` for later use. Dereferencing it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: `head_node<T> newNode = {from,&dummy};` = not good. you're storing the address of an automatic in a container that expects lifetime *outside* of the scope containing said-variable.